# Error while writing unit tests for nested function in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyspark, mocking, nose

I have a function which reads data from db, modifies it and writes it back to another db. I am trying to write unit tests for this

```
import file1
import file2
def update_func(query):
    max_date = file1.get_cutover_date()
    data_dataframe = file2.get_dataframe_from_db(query)
    transformed_dataframe = modify_df(data_dataframe)
    df1 = transformed_dataframe.filter(transformed_dataframe['date']>max_date)
    write_to_db(df1)
```

I tried to patch the function calls.

```
@patch('file2.get_dataframe_from_db')
@patch('file1.get_cutover_date')
test_update_func(patched_get_cutover, patched_get_df):
    patched_get_cutover.return_value = '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
    response = [Row(id=1,date='2016-10-12 00:00:00')]
    response_df = spark.createDataFrame(response)
    patched_get_df.return_value = response_df
    update_func('test_query')
    patched_get_cutover.assert_called
    patched_get_df.assert_called
```

But I am getting TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of MagicMock and MagicMock

Comment: May be you are patching functions in `file1` and `file2` while `update_func()` is in an other file. Try to change `@patch('file2.get_dataframe_from_db')` to `@patch('<file-of-update_func>.get_dataframe_from_db')`.  But I'm not sure.

Comment: All my functions are in different files. Updated my question to include imports

Comment: Change the import to: `from file1 import get_cutover_date` and `from file2 import get_dataframe_from_db`. After that change the patches to: `@patch('<file-of-update_func>.get_dataframe_from_db')` and `@patch('<file-of-update_func>.get_cutover_date')`. I think that with these changes you can solve your problem.

Comment: 1. Post full stack trace, is the exception thrown from `transformed_dataframe['date']>max_date` or elsewhere? 2. If you're using the values returned by a patched function, then you need to ensure the value it returns is "usable". E.g. in this case you're using the output of `file2.get_dataframe_from_db`. So patch it to return a proper dataframe if you really want to use it.